# jags priors in for loop

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I'm trying to minimize my jags code by work with for loop. my original code is

```
data<- list(r1=c(16, 62, 14, 23, 570, 63, 63, 116),
            r2=c(10, 66, 20, 27, 522, 31, 31, 95),
            n1=c(53, 106, 56, 82, 1012, 201, 201, 2049),
            n2=c(53, 107, 94, 82, 1081, 149, 149, 3097))
NS <- length(data$r1) 
library(rjags) 
library(coda)

ma <- function(o){
  out <- "
  model{
  for(i in 1:NS){
  delta[i,1] <- 0
  mu[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001) 
  for(k in 1:2){
  r[i,k] ~ dbin(p[i,k], n[i,k])  
  logit(p[i,k]) <- mu[i] + delta[i,k]  
  }
  delta[i,2] ~ dnorm(lor, prec)  
  }
  lor ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)  
  ############## 1  inverse Gamma Dist.
   tau2 <- 1/prec
   taus <- sqrt(1/prec)

   prec ~ dgamma(0.1,0.1)
  # prec ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
  # prec ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)

  ############## 2 Uniform Dist.
  # tau2 <- tau*tau
  # prec <- 1/tau2
  # taus <- tau

  # tau ~ dunif(0, 2)
  # tau ~ dunif(0, 5)
  # tau ~ dunif(0, 10)

  ### Transform ln(OR) into OR
  OR <- exp ( lor )
  }"
  return(out)
}
```

as you can see I run each prior manually instead of that i would like to run them in a for loop my try;

```
# hyper-parameters
IG <- c(a1=0.1, a2=0.01, a3=0.001,b1=0.1, b2=0.01, b3=0.001)
U <- c(a1=0, a2=0, a3=0, b1=2, b2=5, b3=10)
# priors
prior <- data.frame(IG,U)

if (prior == "IG"){
  for (i in 1:3){
    tau2[i] <- 1/prec[i]
    taus[i] <- sqrt(1/prec[i])
    prec[i] ~ dgamma(a[i],b[i])}
} 

if (prior == "U"){
  for (i in 1:3){
    tau2[i] <- tau[i]*tau[i]
    prec[i] <- 1/tau2[i]
    tau[i] ~ dunif(a[i],b[i])}
}
```

is there any way to do it in rjags, because im not sure if there is an if statement in JAGS software.

Answer (score 0):

There really are not any `if` statements that works that way in `JAGS`, and you will have an error if you are trying to create two `tau`, `taus`, and `prec` objects. There would be two ways to do this. The way I prefer would be to tack on the parameter name to the object. By this I mean:

```
for(i in 1:3){
    # IG priors
    tau2_IG[i] <- 1/prec_IG[i]
    taus_IG[i] <- sqrt(1/prec_IG[i])
    prec_IG[i] ~ dgamma(a_IG[i],b_IG[i])
    # U priors
    tau2_U[i] <- 1/prec_U[i]
    taus_U[i] <- sqrt(1/prec_U[i])
    prec_U[i] ~ dgamma(a_U[i],b_U[i])
}
```

The other way to do it would be to just determine the total number of priors you need for both of these (which in this example would be 6). However, that requires you to make sure you input them in the correct place throughout the model (and then you have to remember what parameters `tau[1:3]` are tied to compared to `tau[1:6]`.

I cannot really see how you plan to relate your second code block (with all of your hyperparameters) back to the `JAGS` model (which only has 1 `prec` prior), but hopefully this example helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still dont know how it works in my example? could you please show me how `delta` in my model are going to be according to your answer?

Comment: Your example lacks enough information to indicate how you want to fit those two pieces together.